# python panel.interact not creating the UI widgets when the function argument is a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dashboard, ipywidgets

I am using `panel` module of python in the `jupyter notebook`, I am using the it's `interact` function which is responsible for generating the GUI widgets automatically based on the values of the arguments of the function. But I have one list which contains the values which can be used to make the GUI widgets but when I pass the list as input to the function ans use the `panel.interact(function_name)`, It don't create the GUI for those values parameters.

suppose I have list containing following values

```
data= ['some_text', 10]
```

and I am passing this as argument to the function. i.e:

```
def fun(data):
```

so i want when I use `panel.interact(fun)`
one `TextInput` and one `IntSlider` should come.
but it's not happening but instead if i give those values in the function arguments like below:

```
def fun(data1='sometext', data2=10):
```

then it generate the `TextInput` and `IntSlider`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a usage question which should be filed on the Discourse.

That said if you want variable arguments you will have to make your function accept kwargs and then provide the kwargs to the interact call:

```
def fn(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

kwargs = {'a': 'text', 'b': 10}

pn.interact(fn, **kwargs)
```

Using args and a list like you are suggesting is not supported.

link ref: https://github.com/holoviz/panel/issues/2308